# Google Analytics Filters

Tags: filter, google-analytics

What expression would be the correct filter to include only data from urls that contain a specific param. For example I have &utm_medium=paid contained in a referral url. What expression would I use?

Answer (score 0):

UTM parameters are automatically mapped to the campaign fields in Google Analytics. The name of the fields in the filters depends on if you are using a (permanent) view filter or an ad hoc filter in the reporting interface.

In the view filters you'd use a custom filter with "campaign medium" as filter field.

In the ad hoc-filters (the box top right of the data tables) and in segmentation it's simply called "campaign". In the ad hoc filters the field is only available if the data table itself displays the campaign as (primary or secondary) dimension.

If you want to filter by a parameter that is not an Analytics utm parameter you would use the request uri (view filters) or page (ad hoc filters) field. Most people have filters that strip url parameters before the data is sent to the reports, so this might not work properly in your ad hoc filters.